# Design Effect in Cluster Randomised Trials

Tags: experiment-design, hierarchical-clustering, intraclass-correlation, clustered-standard-errors, variance-inflation-factor

I want to understand why and how variance inflation factor is taken in account with the formula [1+(m-1)*ICC], where M= Size of clusters and ICC is the intracluster correlation.

As I have deduced till now, the total sample size (m*k) = variance within clusters + variance between clusters.
Can anyone help understand the idea behind it?